# Python Attribute Error - Type Object has no Attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing some code for a project at school.  I am reading in a List that I have created as a text file with 5 attributes.  This is my class object code:

```
class studentclass(object):
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,classno,correct,mydate):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.classno = classno
        self.correct = correct
        self.mydate = mydate
```

Later in the program I am using this code to read in the data, sort it and perform some calculations:

```
myList = [studentclass]
totalnoofrecords = 0
counter = 0

for counter in range(0,totalnoofrecords):
    firstname = myList.firstname[counter]
    lastname = myList.lastname[counter]
    classno = myList.classno[counter]
    correct = myList.correct[counter]
    mydate = myList.mydate[counter]
    newname = myList.firstname[counter +1]
    if newname == firstname:
            grade = grade + studentclass.correct(counter +1)
            nummberofattempts = 2
    newname2 = studentclass.firstname(counter +2)
    if newname2 == firstname:
            grade = grade + studentclass.correct(counter +2)
            nummberofattempts = 3
    mean = grade / numberofattempts

    print ("num ",counter ,"=", myList[counter])
```

But it does not work.  I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'firstname'

The error message points to this line of the code:

> firstname = myList.firstname[counter]

Hoping that someone call help me please. Thanks

Comment: Your `myList` is a list, not a class instance. Lists have no attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are referencing `mylist.firstname`. What is `mylist`? It's a list. Does it have a `firstname` attribute? The error is telling you that it doesn't, and looking at the code you aren't adding that attribute to the list.

*Each element* of the list has that attribute, however. Perhaps you meant to get the `firstname` attribute of one of the elements of the list. Maybe the following, perhaps?

```
for counter in range(0,totalnoofrecords):
    firstname = myList[counter].firstname
    lastname = myList[counter].lastname
    ...
```

In python, when you get an error like "object X has no attribute Y", you can usually rely on that being a true statement. So, ask youself "why does X not have that attribute?". It's usually either a) you forgot to define that attribute, b) you misspelled the attribute or you misspelled X, or c) X isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Good answer, except you should iterate directly over my list, not over a range.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues.  As Alex S. pointed out, your myList is a List, and specifically it is a list with one element: a class constructor.
I think what you want is something like:

```
  # assumption: you have textlines, 
  # which is an array of lines of the form firstname,lastname,blah
  myList = [studentclass(*(args.split(",")) for args in textlines]
```

And then do `myList[counter].firstname` to get the (counter-th) firstname value